# Errors when retrieving values from database determined by combobox to gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview, combobox

I have a code to get all the values from database determined by a combobox to a datagridview.
But whenever i run it , i get invalid column name for ListU.SelectedValue , and the multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRowView" could not be bound if i am using ListU.SelectedItem.

where did i go wrong? i am guessing it is either my code or it is my table.

```
private void User_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            SqlDataAdapter daSearch = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT cName FROM ComDet", conn);
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            ListU.DataSource = dt1;
            daSearch.Fill(dt1);
            ListU.ValueMember = "cName";
            ListU.DisplayMember = "cName";
            ListU.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            ListU.Enabled = true;
}
```

and the button code -

```
private void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PEWPEWDIEPIE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
    conn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter daS = new SqlDataAdapter("select cName, cDetails, cDetails2 from ComDet where cName =" + ListU.SelectedValue, conn);
    DataTable dts3 = new DataTable();
    daS.Fill(dts3);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dts3.DefaultView;
    dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Try with `SqlDataAdapter daS = new SqlDataAdapter("select cName, cDetails, cDetails2 from ComDet where cName = '" + (string)ListU.SelectedItem + "'", conn);`

Comment: @Jigsore - didnt work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use SqlParameter ... helps against sql injection problems and also against missing quotes ... like this:

```
SqlDataAdapter daS = new SqlDataAdapter("select cName, cDetails, cDetails2 from ComDet where cName = @name", conn);
daS.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ListU.SelectedValue;
```

this assumes that cName is a string ... if not you'll have to change the SqlDbType ...